# C#3.0 Automatic properties with extra logic

Tags: c#-3.0, automatic-properties

How can I rewrite he following code using C#3.0 automatic properties?

```
private int _myValue;
        public int MyProperty 
        {
            get { return _myValue;}
            set
            {
                if (value > 0)
                {
                    _myValue = value;
                }
            }
        }
```

If it is not possible, What is the alternative?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, automatically implemented properties have no declared implementation.  Any extended implementation that you wish to provide would have to use a regular property.

I am not sure what you are looking for in terms of an alternative - the syntax you have used in your question *is* the alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: You can't do this with automatic properties.

Comment: What is the alternative way to achieve this?