# C# Automatic Properties set

Tags: c#, properties

I read a zillion articles on Auto Properties and can't come up with a reason for NOT doing something like the following example. Am I missing something here; i.e. is there any reason I should use regular properties in this example? I do it regularly and it works fine.

In a different thread here on StackOverflow ( [C#3.0 Automatic properties with extra logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620156/c3-0-automatic-properties-with-extra-logic) ) the answer was declared to be No as in "No, automatically implemented properties have no declared implementation. Any extended implementation that you wish to provide would have to use a regular property."

```
    class Foobar
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool Scary { get; private set; }

    public void Describe(int size)
    {
        if (size <= 3)
        {
            switch (size)
            {
                case 1:
                    Description = "Cute";
                    Scary = false;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Description = "Interesting";
                    Scary = false;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Description = "Interesting";
                    Scary = false;
                    break;
            }                
        }
        else if (size > 4 && size < 10)
        {
            Description = "I'm sweating!";
            Scary = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Description = "I'm outta here - every man for himself";
            Scary = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you posted looks fine to me. I think that other thread was just saying "if you add logic to automatic properties, they they are no longer automatic."

Comment: I can't understand from your question what idea/concept you're concerned about.

Comment: I don't get what the problem is.

Comment: What you have shown (Describe) is a method. The automatic properties at the top are just the equivalent syntactic sugar for getters/setters to a property and given that you can generate default automatic property stubs in Visual Studio by typing prop[TAB][TAB] I would use auto props... Implementing extra logic in them is easy also and tbh I would never go back to manually writing getters/setters

Comment: @PaulSullivan It's quite common to *need* to use manually defined getters/setters.  You can often get away with auto implementations, but there are plenty of examples, such as having a property firing an event whenever it's changed, that can't be done with an auto-implemented property.

Comment: @Servy Think theres a bit of confusion here... Automatic properties replace manually defined getters/setters (type propfull[TAB][TAB] in visual studio 2010+ (and probably previous versions)). This will define a property with get and set returning a private backing variable by default but you can add all the custom logic you like imbetween the braces of the get{}/set{}... In essence they give you all the goodness with fewer keystrokes :)

Comment: @PaulSullivan An auto implemented property is something of the form: `public int Value {get;set;}`.  You cannot use an auto-implemented property and do any custom logic in the get/set method; it will only get/set the value from the private backing field.  If you want to do more, you need to define your own backing field, get and set the value of it in each method, and *then* add your custom logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not adding code to the get/set methods for your properties, you're adding an entirely separate method to the class which *uses* the get/set properties.

If someone uses the set methods for `Description` or `Scary` directly, rather than using `Describe`, no custom logic is executed.  As an example, nothing prevents someone from doing: `obj.Describe(10); obj.Description = "Cute";`.  If you overloaded the `set` method for those properties you could prevent someone from creating such a cute and scary object.

The answer in the question that you've linked to is perfectly correct; you cannot add validation to the get/set methods of an auto-implemented property; if you want to you need to explicitly define the get/set methods.

Comment: I agree, the setter for `Description` should also be private.

Comment: @Jeff Also note that adding logic to setters also prevents it from being used incorrectly in other methods of the class definition.  That may or may not be desirable.

Comment: Thanks Servy. Assuming you're correct that is the first explanation I've read that makes sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted makes use of automatically implemented properties, and is fine.

It's important to understand that logically, your auto-properties are the same as this:

```
private string _description;
public string Description 
{ 
    get { return _description; }
    set { _description = value; }
}

private bool _scary;
public bool Scary 
{ 
    get { return _scary; }
}
```

I think understanding this is crucial to understanding why *"Any extended implementation that you wish to provide would have to use a regular property."*

An automatic property can only be logically equivalent to what's above.  In other words, an automatic property is what it is.  It's a shorthand equivalent to the code above.

So if you wanted to include additional or different logic in your properties, then you can't use automatic properties.

For example, your class could be refactored (remember "could" doesn't mean "should") to do away with the `Describe` method all together and encapsulate all of your logic into properties:

```
class Foobar
{
    private int _size;

    public string Description 
    { 
        get 
        {    
            if (_size == 1)
            {
                return "Cute";
            }
            else if (_size < 4)
            {
                return "Interesting";
            }
            else if (_size < 10)
            {
                return "I'm sweating!";
            }
            else
            {
                return "I'm outta here - every man for himself";
            }
        }
    }

    public bool Scary 
    { 
        get
        {
            return _size > 3;
        }
    }

    public Foobar(int size) 
    {
        _size = size;
    }
}
```

But if you did that, you couldn't use automatic properties because you would need more logic than just a simple get/set.

If you're just learning when/how to use automatic properties, then I would suggest to always start by writing out "normal" properties.  Then if you find yourself simply getting/setting a backing variable, then you can refactor to use auto properties.